# Data Binding to a listbox item template not working

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, data-binding, listbox

I have the following code. It builds and runs but does not populate the listbox. Can someone spot the mistake?

```
 <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=questions}" Height="401" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="results" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=question.votes}" FontSize="15" Padding="5" Background="White" Foreground="Black"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=question.answers}" FontSize="15" Padding="5" Background="White" Foreground="Black"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="Auto" Width="249">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=question.title}" FontWeight="Bold" Background="#FF92F2CD" Height="22" Width="229" Foreground="Black"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=question.body}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="43" Width="231" Background="#FFEFEFEF" Foreground="Black"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=question.tags}" Foreground="#FFFF9C00" Background="#FF4E3D3D" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>       
        </ListBox>
        <Button Content="Refresh" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="54" />
    </Grid>




public class question 
{
    public string votes     { get; set; }
    public string answers   { get; set; }
    public string title     { get; set; }
    public string body      { get; set; }
    public string tags      { get; set; }

}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    ObservableCollection<question> questions = new ObservableCollection<question>();

    public MainWindow() 
    {
        questions.Add(new question
        {
            votes = "2",
            answers = "3",
        title = "This is a sample title",
        body = "This is a sample body text. It should wrap and not look like shit when presented.",
        tags = "C#,WPF,XML,JediStyle"

    });
    this.DataContext = this;

    InitializeComponent();

    }
}
```

Comment: are question and questions two different properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding does not work on fields but on properties.

```
ObservableCollection<question> questions = new ObservableCollection<question>();

ObservableCollection<question> MyQuestions
{
    get { return questions; }
}
```

And in XAML

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyQuestions}"
```

You also don't have to specify `question` as a part of path for every binding within particular list item:

`Text="{Binding Path=question.tags}"` should be `Text="{Binding Path=tags}"` or even simpler: `Text="{Binding tags}"`

Answer (score 0):

```
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=questions}" Height="401" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="results" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260" Margin="0,20,0,0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=votes}" FontSize="15" Padding="5" Background="White" Foreground="Black"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=answers}" FontSize="15" Padding="5" Background="White" Foreground="Black"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="Auto" Width="249">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=title}" FontWeight="Bold" Background="#FF92F2CD" Height="22" Width="229" Foreground="Black"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=body}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="43" Width="231" Background="#FFEFEFEF" Foreground="Black"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=tags}" //am not sure from where this tags coming
Foreground="#FFFF9C00" Background="#FF4E3D3D" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>       
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use a ViewModel ...

[Good Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx)

[Another Good Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81484/A-Practical-Quick-start-Tutorial-on-MVVM-in-WPF)

The two articles highlight the benefits of full binding and go into the NotifyPropertyChanged and commands. Worth a read.